# Отключить/включить касания на всех View

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как включить касание на всех View, какие флаги нужно прописать? Отключил я касания вот таким способом, а как включить обратно не сумел нагуглить)

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```